# how ISPs sniff and decrypt https traffic without having users getting a certificate warning?

Tags: twitter, https, intercept

Most of the traffic in internet is based on HTTPS(TLS).  In old times when it was HTTP, it was easy for
ISPs or govermental organizations to sniff anf decrypt user traffic. However today HTTPS is leading protocol and
as known its quite secure. 
Now comes my question. How come legal organizations sniff and decrypt user traffic without raising any message on user device?
One way is acting as MiM but in this case user should trust the certificate that is provided by the prying party. 
Average user may discard the error and continue surfing but a cautious user will stop browsing upon receiving a certificate error. 
In other words, how does an ISP intercept users'  twitter,FB, youtube traffic without letting users know?

Answer (score 0):

A legal company would put their own certificate in the users' browsers to mark it as trusted. Of course this can only be done if they have control of the user's computer.

If this cannot be done, these MiM attack do not work, so it cannot be done by a ISP.